# Node.JS rest API is not accessible from outside when I added SSL to my Linux server

Tags: ssl, https, node.js

This is a testing application i'm doing.

https://cfslpro.com/student_portal/

username : chanu

password : 123456

Before adding HTTPS , this login and everything worked. But now nothing is working. I tried adding following solutions to my NodeJS server.

This is how I configured my server.js file :

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(8080);
httpsServer.listen(7000);
```

I have both HTTP and HTTPS ports opening. 
When I open this link "https://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login" in my browser, it's saying connection is not secure.
And also there's a CORS error coming when I'm trying to access above mentioned URL with username and password.
My domain is protected with HTTPS. Can I bypass to HTTPS and use my REST API in http ? 
This configuration kills me. 
Or do we need to create a fully HTTPS enabled REST API using Node.JS ?

This is the **error** i'm facing.
When trying to login, I'm getting this error :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

do I need to use a proxy server for this ?
what is the simplest solution to fix this ?

Comment: What is "not working"? How does it fail? What is the error? Why are you running an API server on an IP address without a domain name?

Comment: @MichaelHampton please check the question.. i added an error response.

Comment: Yes, you need to proxy NodeJS through Apache so that it is served on your domain name.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm really new to this field. Can you please give me some examples, At least tell me how to solve and add a proxy server ? I got this tutorial , but it's not clear :-( https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/sysadmin_guide/rest_auth_proxy.html

Comment: There are [many tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+run+nodejs+with+apache) out on the Internet. You aren't limited to one.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for your information buddy . If you can, please reccomond me one good solution. A simple one to follow please. Sorry if i'm disturbing you. Tried many solutions online, still no good.

Comment: I can't recommend a solution using apache; I use nginx :)

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelHampton for the support. I will try more..

Comment: the issue is that you creating both http & https server. try to remove the http and let only https server run

Comment: @Tirolel i did that. Still not working -( app.listen(config.port, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
   } else {
        console.log("localhost:7000");
    }
});